# Fragment Transaction Not hiding

Tags: android

I have a `SigninFragment` and a `Button`. When the `Button` is clicked a `SignupFragment` is displayed to the user. I use the code below to perform a `FragmentTransaction` and want the `SignupFragment` to replace the `SigninFragment`, but instead the `SignupFragment` is appearing below the `SigninFragment`. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
    Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    SignUpFragment su = new SignUpFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.SigningIn,  su);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bgmain"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
     android:gravity="center">
        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/SigningIn"
        android:name=".SignInFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:gravity="center"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There might be something wrong with your layout. Please edit the layout of your `Activity` into your question.

Comment: ok i did, now what do you thik is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

In order for a fragment to be replaceable, it must have been added programmatically -- not via XML.

See [here](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/programmatically-working-with-android-fragments/) for a relevant tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

To create the initial fragment by code instead of layout:

Set the id `@+id/SigningIn` to a fragment container (which is usually a `FrameLayout`) in your layout in place of your `<fragment />` tag.

Create the initial fragment by code by doing a `FragmentTransaction` in `onCreate()` of your `Activity`, when `savedInstanceState` is null:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content);
    ...

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        SignInFragment f = new SignInFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.SigningIn, f).commit();
    }
}
```